# Running subprocess while simultaneously grabbing console output

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm running an external binary using a subprocess and it takes an awfully long time to finish the job so I need to get some progress information to put into a progress bar in GUI. The binary does display progress information in the console output, specifically I'm interested in items highlighted:

[image]

The problem is that I'm not sure how to continuously grab this information. I tried to use PIPE and Threading but this doesn't seem to work at all, i.e. for testing purposes I'm trying to grab output and print it to console, but nothing happens. I also tried re-directing the output to a file, but this doesn't work either.

```
    def comm(self, process):
        temp = process.stdout
        print(temp)

    def _convert(self):
        tmpdir = self.TEMPDIRECTORY.name.split('\\')
        tmpdir = '/'.join(tmpdir)
        subprocstring = "{} {} {}"
        subprocstring = subprocstring.format(self.EXE_PATH, self.BMF_FILE, tmpdir, '--add-block-id')
        print(subprocstring)
        h = subprocess.run(subprocstring, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        threading.Thread(target=self.comm, args=h)
```

Anyone knows what should I do to get it properly?

Comment: Explain "doesn't seem to work" (edit the question).

Comment: @MichaelButscher, apologies, updated the post.

Comment: (1) `subprocess.run` returns after the subprocess terminated and is therefore not suitable to receive data from the running process. Use `subprocess.Popen` instead. (2) You never `start`ed the thread.